# How to pass List String to TempData Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Tempada to show a list of error in a msg error,i create a List and in my foreach, each error  find it,  i add a error in my List and later i show this list in TempData

```
public IActionResult Demo()
{
    List<string> LogErros = new List<string>();
    try
    {      
        foreach (var item in somethings)
        {
            // if have some error add to list   
            LogErros.add();
        }
        if (LogErros.Count > 0)
        {
            TempData["error-message"] = LogErros;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

I try this:

```
@if (TempData["error-message"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        @TempData["error-message"]
    </div>
}
```

but get error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvqZb.png)

Comment: You should show us the code that displays this.  I expect your problem is because a call to `.ToString()` on a list wont show all the items of the list, it will say `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` like your image shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TempData["error-message"]` stores a list of strings as an `Object`. So you need to get that first, cast it to a list of strings, loop through each one of them and render it.

*Razor basically calls the `ToString` on the expression (in your case, `object`) and hence you are seeing your current results*

This should work

```
@if (TempData["error-message"] != null)
{
    var errors = TempData["error-message"] as List<string>;
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" >x</button>
        @foreach(var errorMessage in errors)
        {
            <p>@errorMessage</p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

While this works, I recommend not putting a lot of C# code in the view. If it is an asp.net core project, I would recommend creating a tag helper for this. Here is a very simple one.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "messages")]
public class AlertMessagesTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        var messages = ViewContext.TempData["error-message"] as List<string>;
        if (messages != null && messages.Any())
        {
            str.Append("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>");
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                str.AppendFormat("<div>{0}</div>", message);

            }
            str.Append("</div>");
        }
        output.Content.AppendHtml(str.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file, use the `addTagHelper` method to include all the tag helpers from your project

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourAssemblyName
```

Now in your view or layout, you can call this tag helper by using a div element with the `messages` attribute

```
<div messages></div>
```

Feel free to update the tag helper code to render the HTML markup you want for the messages.

For Non-Asp.Net core projects, you can create an html helper method which does the same thing.

Comment: hum :) Don't understand your recommendation. How did you know the OP is using ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Thx for you and maccettura, maybe is not the better way, but work good for what i need for now,

Comment: @CodeNotFound extension methods can be created for both legacy MVC and net core

Comment: @JasonRoner TagHelper feature only exist for ASP.Net Core not ASP.Net MVC so extension method does not help a lot here.

Comment: CodeNotFound , maybe is  because IActionResult  heheh

Comment: `IActionResult` made me think that it is an asp net core project ( and asp,net core has been stable for a while now). The asp net core part was a suggestion to improve the general maintainability of the code. It can be applied to non asp.net core as well (by writing an custom html helper)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are displaying `@TempData["error-message"]` in your view, but `TempData` is [essentially a `Dictionary<string, object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) which means when you access the value at that key, the value is an *object*.

Even if you cast to its actual value (`List<string>`) it will implicitly call `.ToString()`, which wont automatically display the contents of the list if you just use the `@` symbol to render on the page.

First thing you need to do is cast your object to a `List<string>`:

```
var errorMessageList = TempData["error-message"] as List<string>;
```

Then you can iterate over the values in the list:

```
var errorMessageList = TempData["error-message"] as List<string>;
@if (errorMessageList != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        @foreach(var message in errorMessageList)
        {
            @message
        }
    </div>
}
```

Of course you will have to format this how you want, maybe it should be comma separated?  Maybe it should be in their own `<span>`... That is up to you.